# imageLoad and imageStore Seemingly not Defined

Tags: glsl

I'm working on implementing a single pass depth-peeling algorithm by using atomic textures in OpenGL 4.2.  I wrote the following fragment program:

```
#version 420 core
layout(r32i) coherent uniform iimage2D img2D_0;
uniform iimage2D img2D_1;
in vec3 pos;
vec4 insert(vec4 data, float new_data) {
    if      (new_data<data.x) return vec4(      new_data,data.xyz);
    else if (new_data<data.y) return vec4(data.x,new_data,data.yz);
    else if (new_data<data.z) return vec4(data.xy,new_data,data.z);
    else if (new_data<data.w) return vec4(data.xyz,new_data      );
    else                      return data;
}
void main() {
    ivec2 coord = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
    while (imageAtomicCompSwap(img2D_0,coord,0,1)==1);
    vec4 depths = imageLoad(img2D_1,coord);
    depths = insert(depths,gl_FragCoord.z);
    imageStore(img2D_1,coord,depths);
    memoryBarrier();
    imageAtomicExchange(img2D_0,coord,0);
}
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
Fragment info
-------------
0(15) : error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "imageLoad(struct iimage2D, ivec2)"
0(17) : error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "imageStore(struct iimage2D, ivec2, vec4)
```

I note that I am using #version 420 in the shader, and I checked the functions' declarations in the documentation ([imageLoad](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/imageLoad.xml), [imageStore](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/imageStore.xml)) and they seem to match.  Curiously, imageAtomicCompSwap, memoryBarrier, and imageAtomicExchange seem to be defined.  Why could these errors occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
uniform iimage2D img2D_1;
```

This is not a valid image definition. You *must* use `layout()` to define its image format, unless you have declared it `writeonly`. It should have errored out on this line, but it interpreted it as some kind of struct definition. So it errored out later when you tried to use it.

Comment: Thanks; I changed it to "layout(RGBA32F) uniform image2D" and it compiles.

Comment: @IanMallett: BTW, you may want to submit the error as a driver bug to NVIDIA or AMD. They should clean up the error message to be more obvious.